# Wix condition for Feature

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.5

I have two Features in my Wix file

1. AppServer
2. Online

AppServer feature gets installed by default, Online should get install only if SQL Server 2012 express installation exists on box. For that I'm doing search in the registry to get SQL Server version.

**Registry Search:**

```
<Property Id="SQLSERVER_INSTANCE" Secure="yes">
  <RegistrySearch Id="SQLServerRegSearch" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft Sql Server\Instance Names\SQL" Type="raw" Name="MSSQLSERVER" />
</Property>

 <Feature Id="Online" ConfigurableDirectory="INSTALLDIR" Level="10" Description="Online" Title="Online Platform">
    <Condition Level="0">SQLSERVER_INSTANCE <> "MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER"</Condition>
    <ComponentRef Id="CompConfig" />
 </Feature>
```

**Problem:**
Even if the box is not having SQL Server 2012 Online Feature is getting installed, Also is it possible to show message if sql server is not found.

Looks like I'm missing something, Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Could you please check what value msi is fetching for session variable [SQLSERVER_INSTANCE]. Alternate condition <Condition Level="0"><![CDATA[SQLSERVER_INSTANCE <> "MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER"]]> </Condition>

Comment: Have you logged the installer?  Is the property getting a value?